# Go Modules "unknown revision" error when using commit hash

Tags: go

I need to pull [this](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core/commit/aca080dccfc2) commit into my go project.

I've tried multiple versions of `go.mod`:

```
...

require (
    github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@v0.0.7-0.20190626134135-aca080dccfc2

    // and...
    github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core v0.0.0-20190626-aca080dccfc2c9933df66baafe6cf9cc4f429825
)

...
```

Both result in errors when running `$ go build`:

```sh
$ go build
go: finding github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core v0.0.0-20190626-aca080dccfc2c9933df66baafe6cf9cc4f429825
go: finding github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core v0.0.7-0.20190626134135-aca080dccfc2
go: github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@v0.0.0-20190626-aca080dccfc2c9933df66baafe6cf9cc4f429825: unknown revision v0.0.0-20190626-aca080dccfc2c9933df66baafe6cf9cc4f429825
go: github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@v0.0.7-0.20190626134135-aca080dccfc2: unknown revision aca080dccfc2
go: error loading module requirements
```

Go getting doesn't work, either:

```sh
$ go get github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@aca080dccfc2c9933df66baafe6cf9cc4f429825
go: finding github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core v0.0.7-0.20190626134135-aca080dccfc2                                                                                                    go: github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@v0.0.7-0.20190626134135-aca080dccfc2: unknown revision aca080dccfc2
go: error loading module requirements
```

As @JimB points out, that hash wasn't merged and was rebased. So I tried to replace it with a new one, but it's still trying to fetch the old one?

```sh
$ go get github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@v0.2.1-0.20190802003216-436d707f7cd0
go: finding github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core v0.0.7-0.20190626134135-aca080dccfc2
go: github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@v0.0.7-0.20190626134135-aca080dccfc2: unknown revision aca080dccfc2
go: error loading module requirements
```

Comment: That commit doesn't exist, it wasn't merged to master, was rebased into a different hash, etc.

Comment: @JimB great catch. I tried getting a more recent hash but it's still trying to find the first one I requested?

Comment: Do you still have the invalid one in `go.mod`? Maybe you managed to store something in `go.sum`? Don't try to create the pseudo version strings yourself (neither of your `go.mod` lines are correct). If you want a specific commit or branch, use `go get` to fetch it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your most recent hash `aca080dccfc2`, was that merged to master, or what does that hash correspond to? From quick look, `aca080dccfc2` does not appear to be on `master`, but I'm not sure what your expectations are regarding that commit.

There are restrictions on what hashes are allowed with modules, for example from this slightly older comment in 
[#27043](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27043#issuecomment-413900418):

> It is present in Git if you look at refs/pulls/nnnnn or whatever the ref is,
>   but not in the main branches and tags.
>   Recent changes cut the search down to main branches and tags,
>   which is more appropriate.

Trying to get that `aca080dccfc2` hash does not work for me:

```
$ go get github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@436d707f7cd0
go: finding github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core 436d707f7cd0
go get github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@436d707f7cd0: 
 github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@436d707f7cd0: invalid version: unknown revision 436d707f7cd0
```

On the other hand, the most recent commit on `master` does work for me:

```
$ go get github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@d204016fc64589d0
```

(Side note: notice I was just using the commit hash by itself after the `@`. That can be handy in case there is something wrong with a [pseudo-version](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions)).

You mentioned:

> it's still trying to fetch the old one?

I'm not sure if that is your primary issue, but in general if you are not sure where a version is coming from, a good place to start is often:

`go mod graph | grep <module-of-interest>`

or in your case:

`go mod graph | grep go-libp2p-core`

From the documentation:

> 'go mod graph' prints the module requirement graph (with replacements applied) in text form. Each line in the output has two space-separated fields: a module and one of its requirements. Each module is identified as a string of the form path@version, except for the main module, which has no @version suffix.

There are some more general troubleshooting tips for tracking down why a particular version is being used in this FAQ on the modules wiki:

[FAQ: What can I check if I am not seeing the expected version of a dependency?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#what-can-i-check-if-i-am-not-seeing-the-expected-version-of-a-dependency)

That said, it might be more interesting to first understand what commit you are expecting to work...

Comment: Thanks for the great response! I was trying to get that commit because it was specified in a go.mod for a project I was working on. I ended up pulling the latest branch and updating the go.mod file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this little hack to solve the issue :

Remove the entries of `github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core v0.0.7-0.20190626134135-aca080dccfc2` from both the **go.mod** & **go.sum** files.

and then try `go get "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@v0.2.1-0.20190802003216-436d707f7cd0"` will download the specified version